# max function implementation on underscore

Tags: javascript, performance, underscore.js

I am in a code-reviewing some popular js, and I begun with underscore.js.

Now I am analyzing the _.max function :

```
  _.max = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
var result = -Infinity, lastComputed = -Infinity,
    value, computed;
if (iteratee == null && obj != null) {
  obj = obj.length === +obj.length ? obj : _.values(obj);
  for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
    value = obj[i];
    if (value > result) {
      result = value;
    }
  }
} else {
  iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);
  _.each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
    computed = iteratee(value, index, list);
    if (computed > lastComputed || computed === -Infinity && result === -Infinity) {
      result = value;
      lastComputed = computed;
    }
  });
}
return result;
};
```

And I don't understand why it is used

`computed > lastComputed || computed === -Infinity && result === -Infinity`

instead of

`computed > lastComputed`

in the if condition when an iteratee is provided.

I think It is more performant ( very little ) if it only use "computed > lastComputed"
in any case where an -Infinity appear in a collection ( one, some, or all elements ).

If I am wrong, I wants to know what.

Thanks,
Pablo Benito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might or might not perform better, but it would certainly perform **differently**. Apparently the Underscore authors wanted it to perform the way it performs.

One way in which it would perform differently is for a one-element collection for which the (misnamed) `iteratee` returns `-Infinity`:

```js
var yourMax = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
  var result = -Infinity, lastComputed = -Infinity,
      value, computed;
  if (iteratee == null && obj != null) {
    obj = obj.length === +obj.length ? obj : _.values(obj);
    for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
      value = obj[i];
      if (value > result) {
        result = value;
      }
    }
  } else {
    iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);
    _.each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      computed = iteratee(value, index, list);
      if (computed > lastComputed) {
        result = value;
        lastComputed = computed;
      }
    });
  }
  return result;
};

var result;
var entries = [{name: 'foo', value: 42}];
result = _.max(entries, function(entry){
  return entry.name === 'foo' ? -Infinity : entry.value;
});
snippet.log("_.max Result: " + result.name);

result = yourMax(entries, function(entry){
  return entry.name === 'foo' ? -Infinity : entry.value;
});
snippet.log("yourMax Result: " + result.name);
```

```html
<!-- Temporary snippet object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="http://jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

If you want to micro-optimize it, a change that doesn't change how it works would be to declare `computed` *within* the `_.each` callback rather than in the containing scope, since it's only ever used within that callback. In theory, when resolving `computed`, the engine has to look at the binding object for the context of the call to the callback first and then, not finding it there, look at the outer binding object to find it. So by moving it closer to where it's actually used, we let the engine find it immediately rather than having that initial miss:

```
_.bettermax = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    var result = -Infinity,
        lastComputed = -Infinity,
        value; // <=== `computed` not declared here
    if (iteratee == null && obj != null) {
        obj = obj.length === +obj.length ? obj : _.values(obj);
        for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
            value = obj[i];
            if (value > result) {
                result = value;
            }
        }
    } else {
        iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);
        _.each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
            // vv `computed` declared here
            var computed = iteratee(value, index, list);
            if (computed > lastComputed || computed === -Infinity && result === -Infinity) {
                result = value;
                lastComputed = computed;
            }
        });
    }
    return result;
};
```

The gain is tiny, but perceptible: http://jsperf.com/move-variable-closer-to-use

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @T.J. Crowder, now I understand the difference.

When the if condition is:

`( computed > lastComputed || computed === -Infinity && result === -Infinity )`

And you have a collection with one or more elements like entries1 below:

```
var
    entries1 = [
        { prop1: -Infinity, prop2: 0 },
        { prop1: -Infinity, prop2: 1 },
        { prop1: -Infinity, prop2: 2 },
        { prop1: -Infinity, prop2: 3 } 
    ],
    entries2 = [
        { prop1: 0, prop2: 0 },
        { prop1: 0, prop2: 1 },
        { prop1: 0, prop2: 2 },
        { prop1: 0, prop2: 3 } 
    ],
    iteratee = function ( entry ) { return entry.prop1; };
```

And all returns -Infinity when are evaluated in the iteratee function, the condition under discussion:

`( computed > lastComputed || computed === -Infinity && result === -Infinity )`

, lets returns at least an element, the first one.

And the condition I suggested:

`( computed > lastComputed )`

Only returns the initializationValue that means -Infinity.

What is better with the original condition, is that the behavior is the same for entries2,
I mean, returns the first element. So, is a good solution

I would do only a little observation, and this is the initialization value for result,

```
_.max2 = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    var
      resultInitialization = {},
      result = resultInitialization, lastComputed = -Infinity,
  value, computed;
if (iteratee == null && obj != null) {
  obj = obj.length === +obj.length ? obj : _.values(obj);
  for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
    value = obj[i];
    if (value > result) {
      result = value;
    }
  }
} else {
  iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);
  _.each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
    computed = iteratee(value, index, list);
    if ( computed > lastComputed ) {
      result = value;
      lastComputed = computed;
    }
  });

  result = ( result !== resultInitialization ) ? result : _.values( obj )[ 0 ];
}
return result;
```

};

With this version, like the original one, will returns the first element for entries1 and entries2, and when an empty list is provided, it returns undefined, may be is semantically better than -Infinity.